# Aggregation using CASE

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called `country`:

```
CountryName | Sales
A             200
B             100
C             300
D             500
E             400
```

Now I in my report I have hardcoded the parameter of region that the user will select, such as `RegionEast`, `RegionWest` etc.

My requirement is that if I select `RegionWest` then I should aggregate countries (`A`, `C`). If (`B`, `D`) then `RegionEast`. There is no explicit relationship of a region with a country in the database.

I was trying to write my query like this:

```
Case When Parameter ='RegionWest' Then Country in (A,C)
     when Parameter ='RegionEast' Then Country in (B,D)
 Else Country
```

But that is not working as expected. Can somebody help?

Comment: You probably need where: `WHERE (Parameter ='RegionWest' AND Country IN ('A','C')) OR (Parameter ='RegionEast' AND Country IN ('B','D'))`

Comment: Why don't you have a lookup table with the desired mapping?

Comment: Wha do you mean by "aggregate countries"?

Answer (score 0):

The CASE you wrote is for visualization (`SELECT`) or for filter data (`WHERE`).

if is the `SELECT` case, then can be (not sure if you want an `SUM(Sales)`:

```
SELECT
  (CASE WHEN Parameter = 'RegionWest' THEN 'A,C'
        WHEN Parameter = 'RegionEast' THEN 'B,D'
  ELSE Country) AS CountryName, Sales
FROM yourTable
```

If is the `WHERE` case I need more of your SQL to understand your question.